# How to flatten message with mutable structure into protobuf?

Tags: parsing, go, protocol-buffers

My proto buf format is this:

```
package main;

message Test {
  optional string id = 1;
  optional string name = 2;
  optional string age = 3;
}
```

Then I populate the protobuf files from the input in golang using the following code. str is already parsed.

```
test = &Test{
  id: proto.String(str[0]),
  name:  proto.String(str[1]),
  age: proto.String(str[2]),
},
```

One condition I have to handle is that one or more optional fields in the Test structure could be absent randomly and I do not know that in advance. How do I handle that in golang?

To give more context, the real data can look like these in the file:

```
id=1, name=peter, age=24
id=2, age=30
name=mary, age=31
id=100
name=bob
age=11
```

Comment: Can you not simply check `if arg[n] == ""` ?

Comment: No. Any field can be gone and I dont know which one is missing if i just check length

Comment: Are you parsing command line arguments? If so, use the https://godoc.org/flag package. Otherwise, we need a little more context where these args are coming from.

Comment: I am parsing files. Thing about the arg are already parsed into proper values.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear, take a look at my update. I posted the file structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to change your input strings into valid JSON, the use the `encoding/json` package to parse it. This has the advantage of letting the `json` parser take care of everything for you. Here is the regex for your particular case.

Basically, the regex looks for `field=value` and replaces with `"field" : "value"` and wraps it in `{}` to create valid JSON. The commas are left as is.

https://play.golang.org/p/_EEdTB6sve

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "regexp"
)

var ins = []string{
    `id=1, name=peter, age=24`,
    `id=2, age=30`,
    `name=mary, age=31`,
    `id=100`,
    `name=bob`,
    `age=11`,
}

var ParseError = errors.New("bad parser input")
var Regex *regexp.Regexp

type Test struct {
    ID   string
    Name string
    Age  string
}

func (t *Test) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("ID: %s, Name: %s, Age: %s", t.ID, t.Name, t.Age)
}

func main() {
    var err error
    Regex, err = regexp.Compile(`([^,\s]*)=([^,\s]*)`)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    for _, v := range ins {

        test, err := ParseLine(v)
        if err != nil {
            log.Panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(test)
    }
}

func ParseLine(inp string) (*Test, error) {
    JSON := fmt.Sprintf("{%s}", Regex.ReplaceAllString(inp, `"$1" : "$2"`))
    test := &Test{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(JSON), test)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return test, nil
}
```

Here is what I believe to be a minimum working case for what you are after, though I am not familiar enough with protocol buffers to get the strings to print right... or even verify if they are correct. Note that this doesn't run in the playground.

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "regexp"
    "github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb"
    _ "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
)

var ins = []string{
    `id=1, name=peter, age=24`,
    `id=2, age=30`,
    `name=mary, age=31`,
    `id=100`,
    `name=bob`,
    `age=11`,
}

var ParseError = errors.New("bad parser input")
var Regex *regexp.Regexp

type Test struct {
    ID   *string `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=id,json=id" json:"id,omitempty"`
    Name *string `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=name,json=name" json:"name,omitempty"`
    Age  *string `protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=age,json=age" json:"age,omitempty"`
}

func (t *Test) Reset() {
    *t = Test{}
}


func (*Test) ProtoMessage() {}
func (*Test) Descriptor() ([]byte, []int) {return []byte{}, []int{0}}

func (t *Test) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("ID: %v, Name: %v, Age: %v", t.ID, t.Name, t.Age)
}

func main() {
    var err error
    Regex, err = regexp.Compile(`([^,\s]*)=([^,\s]*)`)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    for _, v := range ins {

        test, err := ParseLine(v)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            log.Panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(test)
    }
}

func ParseLine(inp string) (*Test, error) {
    JSON := fmt.Sprintf("{%s}", Regex.ReplaceAllString(inp, `"$1" : "$2"`))
    test := &Test{}
    err := jsonpb.UnmarshalString(JSON, test)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return test, nil
}
```

Comment: The parsing is nice. But my main question is how to serialize this into protobuf? I.e., If we see some fields are missing in protobuf, dont populate it.

Comment: Ah yes, let me get to that. I guess I'll make it as generic as possible

Comment: Looks like there is a json package specific to protocol buffers. https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb . Admittedly, I haven't really ever used protocol buffers myself, so I'm not sure how much I can help with that. Plus, that package is not a standard package, so it can't be run in the playground. Take a look and tell me if it is straightforward enough.

Comment: Give that a try now. Also, may I just add that using a gigantic switch statement as in my other answer would result in more efficient code. The json parsers are notoriously expensive. However, as long as each item is less than thousands of characters, you should be fine.

Comment: I think that is doing redundant work by converting from file format to json, then json to pb while I should do file to pb directly. Performance will be impacted by doing redundant work.

Comment: Which is what I was trying to accomplish with my first answer. You could directly assign the pb struct values in the switch statement. Doing it this way just makes it more convenient.

Comment: The first solution did not take care of the "too many fields" problem I mentioned. I want to avoid using lots of switch and case if I have, say 30 fields.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142674/discussion-between-drdot-and-rayfenwindspear).

Comment: I think this method is smart. However, I have one last problem with it before I accept it as the answer. After jsonpb.UnmarshalString(JSON, test), "test" should have the protobuf content. However, if I do fmt.Println(test), then it does not print the value as string, it prints them as address. Could you tell me how to print the actual protobuf value out?

Comment: There seems to be a bug in jsonpb...I will open another question for that. Thank you for answering this question. Here is the new question about the bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43686507/why-is-the-protobuf-marshall-and-unmarshall-returns-different-results-from-befor

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can write the parser for each line of your input something like the following.

NOTE: I didn't make the struct with `proto` values because as an external package, it can't be imported in the playground.

https://play.golang.org/p/hLZvbiMMlZ

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

var ins = []string{
    `id=1, name=peter, age=24`,
    `id=2, age=30`,
    `name=mary, age=31`,
    `id=100`,
    `name=bob`,
    `age=11`,
}

var ParseError = errors.New("bad parser input")

type Test struct {
    ID   string
    Name string
    Age  string
}

func (t *Test) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("ID: %s, Name: %s, Age: %s", t.ID, t.Name, t.Age)
}

func main() {
    for _, v := range ins {
        t, err := ParseLine(v)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(t)
        }
    }
}

func ParseLine(inp string) (*Test, error) {
    splt := strings.Split(inp, ",")
    test := &Test{}
    for _, f := range splt {
        fieldVal := strings.Split(strings.TrimSpace(f), "=")
        switch strings.TrimSpace(fieldVal[0]) {
        case "id":
            test.ID = strings.TrimSpace(fieldVal[1])
        case "name":
            test.Name = strings.TrimSpace(fieldVal[1])
        case "age":
            test.Age = strings.TrimSpace(fieldVal[1])
        default:
            return nil, ParseError
        }
    }
    return test, nil
}
```

Comment: Made it more portable just now.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, the number of optional fields can be big and I would like to avoid so many switch case for each field. Is there a way to loop around the struct?

Comment: I have thought about a map. However, I would like to have an ordered structure.

Comment: I have another idea. You can use a regular expression to turn an input line into JSON, then use the `encoding/json` package. This is more costly as far as CPU is concerned though

Comment: My regex is rusty... gimme a minute and I'll have a new answer.